# Using log4net to log to Oracle database doesn't immediately update the database

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, log4net

I am testing log4net in my web application. 
 I am logging errors to a file as well as a table in an Oracle 11g database.

However I am noticing peculiar behavior when I log to the database.

For example I start the app and generate an error.

- I can see the entry logged into the file.
- I do not see the entry in the table in the database.

I then close the application and restart it.
It is at that point I then see the previous error in the oracle table.

I have my root node set as:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_Oracle"/>
</root>
```

The appenders are pretty basic just like any of the examples that I found online.

Oracle Appender:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_Oracle" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <connectionType value="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  <connectionString value="my stuff"/>
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (Datetime,Thread,Log_Level,Logger,Message,STACK_TRACE) VALUES (:log_date, :thread, :log_level, :logger, :message, :stackTrace)"/>
  <bufferSize value="128"/>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":log_date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":thread"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":log_level"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="50"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":logger"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":stackTrace"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{StackTrace}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Comment: can you post the appender itself please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty positive you have an issue with your buffer size in the appender. In your ado appender there should be a line `<bufferSize value ="x" />`

The buffer size is how many errors occur before it write to table. To see live errors change the x to 1.

Comment: You are currently set to 128 so you wont see errors in db until there 128 of them stored to the buffer. It then write to db (or will write if you close and re open.)

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.

Comment: glad to help. Check out this tutorial for a great intro to log4net. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAdQ_QwNww